# having an and condition on multiple rows - sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have the following query where i'm trying to select one value based on a condition

```
select distinct tblItemTypePropValue.ItemType_Fkey, tblItemPrice.price, dbo.fnGetDiscountItemType(tblItemTypePropValue.ItemType_Fkey) as finalPrice 
from tblItemTypePropValue
inner join tblItemPrice
on tblItemTypePropValue.ItemType_Fkey = tblItemPrice.itemType_fkey
where Value_Fkey in (2097,2131)
and tblitemtypepropvalue.ItemType_Fkey in (select id from tblItemType where Item_Fkey = 12241)
```

the problem is i n the where in value_fkey in (2097,2131)

is there a way to write an and condition on multiple rows where value_fkey = 2097 and = 2131.

and also, can it be done without a join since my parameters inside the in can vary in count.

sample result

```
itemtype_fkey   price finalPrice
6191            100       93
```

so the query will only return the ItemType_Fkey that has both Value_Fkeys specified in the query

Value
thanks,

Comment: `Value_Fkey in (2097,2131)` is the same as `(Value_Fkey = 2097 or Value_Fkey = 2131)`.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images). Simplify if needed, [mcve].

Comment: *condition on multiple rows* is usually based on *conditional aggregation*, e.g. `max(case when Value_Fkey = 2097 then 1 end) = 1 and max(case when Value_Fkey = 2131 then 1 end) = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two INNER JOINs and check for the existence of the 2097 and 2131 keys on them.

Being INNER JOINS, only the Prices having both of those keys will be returned.

```
select distinct P.ItemType_Fkey, P.price, 
                dbo.fnGetDiscountItemType(P.ItemType_Fkey) as finalPrice 
from tblItemType T
     inner join tblItemPrice P on P.ItemType_Fkey = T.id
     inner join tblItemTypePropValue V1 on V1.ItemType_Fkey = P.ItemType_Fkey and V1.Value_Fkey = 2097 
     inner join tblItemTypePropValue V2 on V2.ItemType_Fkey = P.ItemType_Fkey and V2.Value_Fkey = 2104 
where T.Item_Fkey = 12241
```

Comment: thank you. is using joins the only way to get this result?

Comment: the final query looked like this. i think you confused the tables.

Comment: select distinct t1.ItemType_Fkey, tblItemPrice.price, dbo.fnGetDiscountItemType(t1.ItemType_Fkey) as finalPrice
from tblItemTypePropValue t1
inner join tblItemPrice
on t1.ItemType_Fkey = tblItemPrice.itemType_fkey
inner join tblItemTypePropValue t2
on t1.ItemType_Fkey = t2.ItemType_Fkey and t1.Value_Fkey = 2097
inner join tblItemTypePropValue t3
on t2.ItemType_Fkey = t3.ItemType_Fkey and t2.Value_Fkey = 2104
where t1.ItemType_Fkey in (select id from tblItemType where Item_Fkey = 12241)

Comment: @ahmadnoori, yes, as far as I know using several JOINS is the only way to check if multiple rows exist at the same time. If you have a variable number of keys to check, you can build that query dynamically. Search for Dynamic SQL. Finally, you are right that I misunderstood the tables, I have fixed the query, notice that you don't nee three JOINS to PropValues, two of them will suffice to check the existence of those two keys. Also, I have replaced the final subquery with a simple JOIN to ensure that we are getting the prices of the Item 12241.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct tblItemTypePropValue.Value_Fkey,tblItemTypePropValue.ItemType_Fkey, tblItemPrice.price, dbo.fnGetDiscountItemType(tblItemTypePropValue.ItemType_Fkey) as finalPrice 
from tblItemTypePropValue
inner join tblItemPrice
on tblItemTypePropValue.ItemType_Fkey = tblItemPrice.itemType_fkey
where ((Value_Fkey = 2097) or (Value_Fkey = 2131))
and tblitemtypepropvalue.ItemType_Fkey in (select id from tblItemType where Item_Fkey = 12241)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want those items where rows for both `Value_Fkey` exist like this

```
SELECT 
    v.ItemType_Fkey,
    max(p.price), -- max/min/avg?
    dbo.fnGetDiscountItemType(v.ItemType_Fkey) AS finalPrice
FROM tblItemTypePropValue AS v
INNER JOIN tblItemPrice AS p
ON v.ItemType_Fkey = p.itemType_fkey
WHERE Value_Fkey IN (2097,2131) --- list of values
  AND v.ItemType_Fkey
  IN ( SELECT id
       FROM tblItemType
       WHERE Item_Fkey = 12241
     )
GROUP BY v.ItemType_Fkey
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Value_Fkey) = 2 -- number of values in list
```

Comment: the query is not returning any results, i updated the question to make it more clear. thanks!

Comment: Your initial query included Value_Fkey, wghich I just copied. Removed it from group by to fix the result.